# Compose Mail in Outlook with Word

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

By mistake, I pressed some shortcut, and now my Compose Mail window, in Outlook 2007 looks like a Word document:

[image]

How to switch between this "Word" window and regular window?

Comment: [Change the message format to HTML, Rich Text, or plain text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-message-format-to-HTML-Rich-Text-or-plain-text-de2acb3d-3330-42a1-b02a-5f582fc6e796)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've managed to switch to Print Layout (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). You need to switch back to Draft Layout: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.